# Write the relational algebra expression to find the manufacturers (maker) of printers which are not colour (color) printers

Tags: algebra, relational

Product(**model**, maker, type)

PC(**model**, speed, ram, hd, price)

Laptop(**model**, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)

Printer(**model**, color, type, price)

so far iv got this: **σ Printer = 'color' (Product join model = model Printer)**

Some help please

Answer (score 0):

You want to select your maker first, then you can join the product and printer table on model. After that put in your selection on Printer.color = false.

This code should work:

```
π maker (Product ⨝ π model (σ color = false (Printer)))
```